# How can I use jquery to check if a string contains a special character?

Tags: jquery, regex

I need to check if a string contains a special character.  I have used regex for other fields, but for this it won't stop the form from being submitted if there is no special character. Whether i use a `!` or not, it always skips this.

```
if (str.search(/[^\!\@@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\_\+\.\,\;\:]/) == -1) {
   alert("Your password must contain at least 1 special character.");
   e.preventDefault();
   return ("bad_char");
}
```

Comment: Looks like you should remove the first `^`. And you overescaped the pattern. BTW, using `RegExp#test()` is a better fit for the check, I think.

Comment: use `/^[a-zA-Z0-9- ]*$/` . It will true only if no special character is there

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```js
if (!/[!@#$%^&*()_+.,;:]/.test("ssss")) {
   alert("Your password must contain at least 1 special character.");
   e.preventDefault();
   return ("bad_char");
}
```

Main points:

- It is better to use `RegExp#test()` to check if there is a match with a regex
- No need escaping the symbols you have inside the character class
- You can "negate" the result of the test and that way make sure the string contains one of those symbols.

Comment: Note: I do not think you need to double the `@` (it is done in Razor only, I believe)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
if(str.match(/[^A-Za-z0-9]/) === null)
{
    // not found
}
else 
{
    // found
}
```

Clarification: If `Char` is not alphanumeric, then it is `Special Character`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do like this

```
if(/^[a-zA-Z0-9- ]*$/.test(str) == false) {
        console.log("contains special character");
    }
```